# Вывод массива или его части начиная с указанной ячейки таблицы

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеется таблица и возвращаемый Ajax-запросом массив данных.
Необходимо выводить данные массива с ячейки формируемой таблицы.

Примечания:
переменная "nCell" задается программно и поэтому может быть в диапазоне от 0 до N-1;
размер массива величина не постоянная, а задается программно.

Пример кода для правки, здесь: https://jsfiddle.net/Mister_X_2k/97tnjhLm

---

Пояснения:
**nCell = 0** - данные выводятся полностью, каждый элемент массива в свою ячейку таблицы;
**nCell > 0** - ячейки чей номер менее заданного остаються пустыми, заполнению подлежат только начиная с "nCell" и до конца массива данных.

```js
var nCell = 1; // номер ячейки с которой начать вывод данных
var sTime = 0.25; // время в секундах вывода данных в ячейки таблицы
var jtable = [1, "Cклад 1", "Cклад 2", "Cклад 3", "Cклад 4", "Cклад 5", "Cклад 6", "Cклад 7"]; // массив данных

ViewTable(jtable, sTime, nCell); //передача внутри Ajax

function ViewTable(data, tdata, iCell) {
  if (typeof iCell == "undefined") iCell = 0;

  var table = $('table tbody');
  table.append("<tr></tr>")
  data.forEach(function(item, i) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (i == 0 && iCell > 0) {
        i = iCell;
        table.find("tr").append('<td> i=' + i +' > iCell='+data[iCell]+'</td>');
        //console.log('1: i=' + i +' > iCell='+data[iCell]);
      }
      if (i != iCell) {
        i = iCell;
        if (i >= data.length) return;
        table.find("tr").append('<td> i=' + i +' > iCell='+data[iCell]+'</td>');
        //console.log('2: i=' + i +' > iCell='+data[iCell]);
      }
      iCell++;
    }, (i + 1) * tdata * 1000)
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" align="center">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>№ п/п</th>
      <th>Данные 1</th>
      <th>Данные 2</th>
      <th>Данные 3</th>
      <th>Данные 4</th>
      <th>Данные 5</th>
      <th>Данные 6</th>
      <th>Данные 7</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="4" style="text-align: left;">Кнопка "НАЗАД"</th>
      <th colspan="4" style="text-align: right;">Кнопка "Отправить"</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: дак вы не хотите рассказать, что в вашем коде работает не так как ожидается?

Comment: в любом случае, таймаут замените на таймер, строку сформируйте сразу целиком, а уже данные вносите по таймеру (если это надо), просто пропустите нужное число ячеек через `eq(...)` и при итерации массива берите `next()`, или все тот же `eq()`

Comment: Добавлены пояснения

Answer (score 0):

## **Всем спасибо за участие в решении данного вопроса.**

Ответ находится [здесь](https://jsfiddle.net/Mister_X_2k/qnskr19v/). Достаточно было в теле функции:

- убрать приращение "*iCell*";
- убрать "*if (i >= data.length) return;*" за ненадобностью;
- правильно выставить условия вывода данных.

---

Теперь независимо от размера массива вывод данных начинается с указанной позиции в массиве, а незадействованные начальные части массива просто не выводятся.

---

```js
var nCell = 3; // номер ячейки с которой начать вывод данных
var sTime = 0.25; // время в секундах вывода данных в ячейки таблицы
var jtable = [1, "Cклад 1", "Cклад 2", "Cклад 3", "Cклад 4", "Cклад 5", "Cклад 6", "Cклад 7"]; // массив данных

ViewTable(jtable, sTime, nCell); //передача внутри Ajax

function ViewTable(data, tdata, iCell) {
  if (typeof iCell == "undefined") iCell = 0;

  var table = $('table tbody');
  table.append("<tr></tr>")
  data.forEach(function(item, i) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (i < iCell) {
        table.find("tr").append('<td></td>');
      } else {
        table.find("tr").append('<td>' + data[i] + '</td>');
      }
    }, (i + 1) * tdata * 1000)
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
<table border="1" align="center">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>№ п/п</th>
      <th>Данные 1</th>
      <th>Данные 2</th>
      <th>Данные 3</th>
      <th>Данные 4</th>
      <th>Данные 5</th>
      <th>Данные 6</th>
      <th>Данные 7</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="4" style="text-align: left;">Кнопка "НАЗАД"</th>
      <th colspan="4" style="text-align: right;">Кнопка "Отправить"</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```